# Copy Data from one Nav DB to another DB's when an insert or Modify Occurs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

My requirement is, I need to copy Newly Inserted or Modifyed Data from one DB to other DB's.

This should be automated and Need an Stored procedure having two configration Files and Job Scheduler in SQL.

```
Configration 1

Source System :
Source DB Cluster :
Source DB:

Destination Systems:....,....;
Destination DB Cluster:....,.....;
Destination DB: .....,.....;

Configration 2

Source Tables:......,......;
Destination Tables:.....,....;
```

For Example 
My Source DB Cluster/Server name :CorStrSdb001.corp.company.com

Destination Cluster/Server name :TSSGMSL050.tss.corp.company.com, TSSGMSL051.tss.corp.company.com

I am using Sql 2008 R2.
Please Help me. Thanks

Comment: Since you have the activity to be performed on insert and update you can use triggers on your source database and linked server connectivity to copy the data.

Comment: Yes, I can write the code to execute the SQL Stored Procedure from application trigger. But in that case the Configuration file also need to be populated from my application.

Comment: What exactly you mean by configuration file need to be populated from application?

Comment: The configration file can be derived outside the application also.